# How to fix an error in a python username and password list program

Tags: python, tkinter

I just created a tkinter where you create a username and password, than you log in and can create or view the items you've added to your list. The username and password part of the program is fine, but when you get to the label adding part, it won't add the list labels.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

 creds = 'tempfile.temp' # This just sets the variable creds to 'tempfile.temp'

def Signup(): # This is the signup definition, 
    global pwordE # These globals just make the variables global to the entire script, meaning any definition can use them
    global nameE
    global roots

    roots = Tk() # This creates the window, just a blank one.
    roots.title('Signup') # This renames the title of said window to 'signup'
    intruction = Label(roots, text='Please Enter new Credidentials\n') # This puts a label, so just a piece of text saying 'please enter blah'
    intruction.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E) # This just puts it in the window, on row 0, col 0. If you want to learn more look up a tkinter tutorial :)

    nameL = Label(roots, text='New Username: ') # This just does the same as above, instead with the text new username.
    pwordL = Label(roots, text='New Password: ') # ^^
    nameL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W) # Same thing as the instruction var just on different rows. :) Tkinter is like that.
    pwordL.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W) # ^^

    nameE = Entry(roots) # This now puts a text box waiting for input.
    pwordE = Entry(roots, show='*') # Same as above, yet 'show="*"' What this does is replace the text with *, like a password box :D
    nameE.grid(row=1, column=1) # You know what this does now :D
    pwordE.grid(row=2, column=1) # ^^

    signupButton = Button(roots, text='Signup', command=FSSignup) # This creates the button with the text 'signup', when you click it, the command 'fssignup' will run. which is the def
    signupButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    roots.mainloop() # This just makes the window keep open, we will destroy it soon

 def FSSignup():
    with open(creds, 'w') as f: # Creates a document using the variable we made at the top.
        f.write(nameE.get()) # nameE is the variable we were storing the input to. Tkinter makes us use .get() to get the actual string.
        f.write('\n') # Splits the line so both variables are on different lines.
        f.write(pwordE.get()) # Same as nameE just with pword var
        f.close() # Closes the file

    roots.destroy() # This will destroy the signup window. :)
    Login() # This will move us onto the login definition :D

def Login():
    global nameEL
    global pwordEL # More globals :D
    global rootA

    rootA = Tk() # This now makes a new window.
    rootA.title('Login') # This makes the window title 'login'

    intruction = Label(rootA, text='Please Login\n') # More labels to tell us what they do
    intruction.grid(sticky=E) # Blahdy Blah

    nameL = Label(rootA, text='Username: ') # More labels
    pwordL = Label(rootA, text='Password: ') # ^
    nameL.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    pwordL.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    nameEL = Entry(rootA) # The entry input
    pwordEL = Entry(rootA, show='*')
    nameEL.grid(row=1, column=1)
    pwordEL.grid(row=2, column=1)

    loginB = Button(rootA, text='Login', command=CheckLogin) # This makes the login button, which will go to the CheckLogin def.
    loginB.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    rmuser = Button(rootA, text='Delete User', fg='red', command=DelUser) # This makes the deluser button. blah go to the deluser def.
    rmuser.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    rootA.mainloop()

def CheckLogin():
    with open(creds) as f:
        data = f.readlines() # This takes the entire document we put the info into and puts it into the data variable
        uname = data[0].rstrip() # Data[0], 0 is the first line, 1 is the second and so on.
        pword = data[1].rstrip() # Using .rstrip() will remove the \n (new line) word from before when we input it




    if nameEL.get() == uname and pwordEL.get() == pword: # Checks to see if you entered the correct data.
        r = Tk() # Opens new window
        r.title(':D')
        r.geometry('250x100') # Makes the window a certain size
        stuff = []
        def addListItem():
            josh = entry100.get()
            stuff.append(josh)
            labels = Label(re, label=stuff)
            labels.pack()

        rlbl = Label(r, text='\n[+] Logged In') # "logged in" label
        rlbl.pack() # Pack is like .grid(), just different
        rlbl = Label(r, text='\nWelcome back, ' + nameEL.get())
        rlbl.pack()
        rlbl = Label(r, text='\nThis is your list: ')
        if len(stuff) == 0:
            re = Tk()
            re.title('suh g, no stuff')
            re.geometry('300x300')
            rlbl = Label(re, text='There is no items in this lists directory')
            rlbl.pack()
            entry100 = Entry(re)
            entry100.pack()
            butt68 = Button(re, text="Create List Item", command=addListItem)
            butt68.pack()
        if len(stuff) != 0:
            re = Tk()
            re.title('items of your list')
            re.geometry('300x300')
            rlbl = Label(re, text=stuff)
        rlbl.pack()
        rlbl = Label
        r.mainloop()
    else:
        r = Tk()
        r.title(':D')
        r.geometry('150x50')
        rlbl = Label(r, text='\n[!] Invalid Login')
        rlbl.pack()
        r.mainloop()

def DelUser():
    os.remove(creds) # Removes the file
    rootA.destroy() # Destroys the login window
    Signup() # And goes back to the start!

if os.path.isfile(creds):
    Login()
else: # This if else statement checks to see if the file exists. If it does it will go to Login, if not it will go to Signup :)
    Signup()
```

The error that shows up is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
   File "/Users/dgranulo/Documents/lovgin.py", line 85, in addListItem
    labels = Label(re, label=stuff)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-label"
```

I think the error has to do with the labels = Label(re, text=stuff), because I am putting a whole list where there should only be one piece of text. If anyone knows how to fix this, that would be greatly appreciated if you could share that with me.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error is telling you, `label` is not something `Label` supports. You need to use `text`.

Comment: how would I put that? I tried changing the label parts with text but it doesn't work

Comment: @DrizzyThaCoder2Account: you only need to look at your own code to get an answer to that question. You use `text` in more than a dozen other labels correctly.